# How to control meeting start time in Google Meet when the access type is set to Open?

Tags: google-meet

I'm using my personal 10-year-old Google account to create scheduled meetings with Google Meet. I am not subscribed to a Google One Premium plan.

I can schedule a meeting from 2 PM to 3 PM but as far as I can see, I can use the link to join it at any time and there's no need to follow the schedule.

Further, as far as I understand, if even a single person joins the meeting in advance, for example at 1:40 pm, the meeting will be interrupted at 2:40 pm when the 1-hour limit for free meetings expires.

I know there is a way to stop guests from joining before the host, but I don't want to control everyone who joins. I want to share the link in advance, so people can use it independently of whether I'm present.

Is there a way to do something in advance to ensure that the meeting is only active from 2 pm to 3 pm, independent of what meeting guests do?

Comment: You should add more details like the kind of account / Workspace edition used, as well as extend the context of the question. The best might be to avoid making "Is there a way..." kind of questions because usually there are many ways but they depend on the competencies that the "user" might have. Please start by reading [Use add-ons with Google Meet](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fmeet%2Fanswer%2F13961388%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=hangouts-meet-v2&product_context=13961388&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=meet)

Comment: If you want to turn the question into an asking for an add-on recommendation, consider asking the question in [softwarerecs.se], otherwise make the question more specific about the "ways" that you are looking for, i.e., if you are open to send the Google Meet link by instant message at the meeting start time and manually push out users at the end of the meeting.

Comment: Isn't "free" is not enough to define the type of account I am on? It's an account created 10 years ago.

Comment: I've added a ton of details, don't know what else to add. It seems like "what are the options for using Google Meet, which I must limit in this question" - is a very complex question on itself. Should I ask it on SE first? I don't know all the options, that's exactly why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

Google Meet is a brand used for several products and services. The online services have several tiers for consumer / free and managed accounts. This answer focuses on settings for scheduled meetings owned by *Free Google Accounts*.

## Free Google Account

Most free accounts have a Gmail email address as the primary account email address, but it's possible to have a Google Account without the Gmail service; in such cases, the primary email address will be from a third-party email service.

#### Google Meet features and limitations for free accounts

1. 60-minute limit on meetings of 3+ participants.
2. `Host must join before anyone else` can be enabled and takes precedence over the selected `Meeting access type` option.
3. You cannot assign a co-host.
4. `Meeting access type` can be set to `Open` or `Trusted`.

#### Option 1: Always Show Up, and On Time

1. Enable the `Host must join before anyone else` option.
2. Set the `Meeting access type` to `Open`.
3. Join the meeting when you want the one-hour countdown timer to be started.

#### Option 2: Google One Premium plan

1. Subscribe to [Google One Premium (2TB) plan](https://one.google.com/about/plans)
2. Set the `Meeting access type` to `Open` if you truly want *anyone* to be able to jump in, or `Trusted` if you want to let Google users you invite skip the waiting room but approve anyone else.
3. You'll now have a 24-hour limit for meetings of 3+ participants, as well as additional features including call recording, and noise cancellation. See the additional features listed in the table **Google One Subscribers** (with 2TB+ of storage) at the bottom of [Premium Meet features for Google Workspace & Google One users](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10459644?hl=en).

Comment: Somehow without a Google One Premium plan, 3 of us were still able to have a 90-minute meeting without being cutoff. Do you know how it is possible?

Comment: Google Meet indicates that ***"For mobile calls and 1:1s, there's no time limit."*** Maybe that meeting qualified?  Also, who hosted the meeting?